# clustering discrete functional data

Tags: clustering, functional-data-analysis

I have a set of data, where each data is of the form $(X, Y)$, $X := (x_1, x_2 \dots x_m) $ and $Y := (f^1_1(X), f^1_2(X) \dots f^1_m(X))$ or $Y := (f^2_1(X), f^2_2(X) \dots f^2_m(X))$. In a data if image of any $x_i$ is from $f^1_i(X)$ then images of all other $x_j$ are from $f^1_j$.  
For example, consider following data:
{((1,1,1), (2,2,1)), 
((4,2,4), (5,4,4)), 
((3,3,5), (2,9,5)), 
((2,2,7), (1,6,7))}
The images(second component) of first two samples are from $f^1_1 := x_1 + 1$, $f^1_2 := 2*x_2$ and $f^1_3 := x_3$ and next two are from $f^2_1(X) := x_1 - 1$, $f^2_2 := 2*x_2 + x_1$ and $f^2_3 := x_3$ 
I want to cluster such data based on whether same set of functions are used (i.e. in above case two clusters with first two samples in one cluster and next two in another) with following constraints:

- Number of clusters is known
- The exact form of function is not known but they can be assumed to be
  linear in $X$
- Number of samples is small (within 100)

I had a look at functional data analysis (*Functional data clustering: A survey*) and the above problem seems to me similar to *raw-data clustering* as I have discrete points and exact form of function is not required. But, I don't understand how high-dimensional vectorial data can be constructed and used here as mentioned in the survey.

Any pointer on understanding existing solutions for this problem will be helpful.

Comment: 1. Most FDA framework characterise rather flexibly their data as the realisations of a stochastic Gaussian process so the actual "*exact form of function*" is unneeded. 2. If it helps you can think functional data as a slightly more generalised version of longitudinal data.